# Need help on why my answer is not correct

Tags: probability

Problem: Suppose that the number of miles that a car can run before its battery dies is exponentially distributed with an average value of $5000$ miles. If Jane desires to take a a $2000$-mile trip, what is the probability that she will be able to complete the trip without replacing the battery?

My approach:

Using $F_x(x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}$, $\lambda$ is $5000$ and $x$ is $2000$, so my answer is $1 - e^{-2/5}$. But the actual answer is $e^(-2/5)$.

Anyone knows why is my approach wrong and the answer is $e^{-2/5}$.

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean $\lambda = \frac1{5000}$

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. The CDF $F_x(x)$ tells you $P(X \leq x)$, which in this case means the chance that her car **DOES** die before $x$ miles. What you want to find in the problem is the chance that her car **DOES NOT** die in $2000$ miles. So you have to do the complement: $$P(X \geq 2000) = 1 - P(X < 2000) = 1 - F_x(2000) = 1 - (1 - e^{-2/5}) = e^{-2/5}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The CDF measures the probability that a random variable takes a value *below* some threshold, which in this corresponds to the battery dying duiring the trip. But here you want the complement, the probability that it takes a value *above* the threshold.